# How to get top values when there is a tie

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count

I am having difficulty figuring out this dang problem. From the data and queries I have given below I am trying to see the email address that has rented the most movies during the month of September.

There are only 4 relevant tables in my database and they have been anonymized and shortened:

Table "**cust**":

| cust_id | f_name | l_name | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | Daniels | jack.daniels@google.com |
| 2 | Jose | Quervo | jose.quervo@yahoo.com |
| 5 | Jim | Beam | jim.beam@protonmail.com |

Table "**rent**"

| inv_id | cust_id | rent_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 9/1/2022 10:29 |
| 11 | 1 | 9/2/2022 18:16 |
| 12 | 1 | 9/2/2022 18:17 |
| 13 | 1 | 9/17/2022 17:34 |
| 14 | 1 | 9/19/2022 6:32 |
| 15 | 1 | 9/19/2022 6:33 |
| 16 | 3 | 9/1/2022 18:45 |
| 17 | 3 | 9/1/2022 18:46 |
| 18 | 3 | 9/2/2022 18:45 |
| 19 | 3 | 9/2/2022 18:46 |
| 20 | 3 | 9/17/2022 18:32 |
| 21 | 3 | 9/19/2022 22:12 |
| 10 | 2 | 9/19/2022 11:43 |
| 11 | 2 | 9/19/2022 11:42 |

Table "**inv**"

| mov_id | inv_id |
| --- | --- |
| 22 | 10 |
| 23 | 11 |
| 24 | 12 |
| 25 | 13 |
| 26 | 14 |
| 27 | 15 |
| 28 | 16 |
| 29 | 17 |
| 30 | 18 |
| 31 | 19 |
| 31 | 20 |
| 32 | 21 |

Table "**mov**":

| mov_id | titl | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | Anaconda | 3.99 |
| 23 | Exorcist | 1.99 |
| 24 | Philadelphia | 3.99 |
| 25 | Quest | 1.99 |
| 26 | Sweden | 1.99 |
| 27 | Speed | 1.99 |
| 28 | Nemo | 1.99 |
| 29 | Zoolander | 5.99 |
| 30 | Truman | 5.99 |
| 31 | Patient | 1.99 |
| 32 | Racer | 3.99 |

and here is my current query progress:

```
SELECT cust.email,
       COUNT(DISTINCT inv.mov_id) AS "Rented_Count"
FROM cust
JOIN rent ON rent.cust_id = cust.cust_id
JOIN inv ON inv.inv_id = rent.inv_id
JOIN mov ON mov.mov_id = inv.mov_id
WHERE rent.rent_date BETWEEN '2022-09-01' AND '2022-09-31'
GROUP BY cust.email
ORDER BY "Rented_Count" DESC;
```

and here is what it outputs:

| email | Rented_Count |
| --- | --- |
| jack.daniels@google.com | 6 |
| jim.beam@protonmail.com | 6 |
| jose.quervo@yahoo.com | 2 |

and what I want it to be outputting:

| email |
| --- |
| jack.daniels@google.com |
| jim.beam@protonmail.com |

From the results I am actually getting I have a tie for first place (Jim and Jack) and that is fine but I would like it to list both tieing email addresses not just Jack's so you cant do anything with rows or max I don't think.

I think it must have something to do with dense_rank but I don't know how to use that specifically in this scenario with the count and Group By?

Your creativity and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `FETCH FIRST ROWS WITH TIES` clause. It will work together with the `ORDER BY` clause to get you the highest values (FIRST ROWS), including ties (WITH TIES).

```
SELECT cust.email
FROM cust
INNER JOIN rent 
        ON rent.cust_id = cust.cust_id
INNER JOIN inv 
        ON inv.inv_id = rent.inv_id
INNER JOIN mov 
        ON mov.mov_id = inv.mov_id
WHERE rent.rent_date BETWEEN '2022-09-01' AND '2022-09-31'
GROUP BY cust.email
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT inv.mov_id) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
```

Comment: One more question: using your solution is there a way to hide the column "Rented_Count" from the results so all that it gives is the email addresses? Removing it from the select statement causes the group by to fail and I don't know a way around that?

Comment: Nice to hear I saved you some time. Sure thing you can remove that. Since you're using it in the `ORDER BY` clause, you need to substitute `ORDER BY "Rented_Count"` with `ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT inv.mov_id)`, otherwise the DBMS can't find the reference anymore.